# SSIS Shared database connection strings between parent and child packages

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, bids

I want to be able to build 30+ packages in SSIS and be able to test/develop them in isolation.  I also want to be able to run these from a Master/Parent package.

When it comes to delivering the SSIS parent package I want to be able to change the connection string once and have this trickle down to all child packages. Other developers will be building and testing without using the master package and want to be able to develop these in isolation.

I've seen many articles on XML config/parameter mappings etc. but I've not seen any definitive guide on how this should be done & what is best practice.

The project we have created also only allows packages to be linked in the solution as an external reference rather than as project links (is this the legacy format?). I'm wondering if this type of project could hamper the ability to achieve shared connection strings.

Comment: One possible option is to apply a catalog, in which you can add the parent and child packages along with defining the different environments and shared variables (connection string) applied by each package.  Take a look at the following link: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/11/13/ssis-server-catalogs-environments-environment-variables-in-ssis-in-denali.aspx

Comment: I can't use SSIS 2012 as I'm constrained by server versions we have. Basically, I'm using the package deployment model, not the project deployment model which is substantially easier to set-up shared config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this myself for reference. Basically there is no streamlined way of doing this in the Package Deployment model. It is much easier to achieve this using the Project Deployment model which is the default in VS2012. However, we don't have this luxury.

I had to create some parent variables contained in the master package. These are then set to the XML config. The child packages then have direct config links to the parent variables, with the target properties mapped to the connection string properties of the connection managers.